# Ubuntu crashes with search bar if I want to searching any things?

Tags: 22.04

I can not search files on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS .. Nautilus always crashes

[image]

When Running Nautilus from the terminal it gave me this error:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: 15:54:00.564: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. 
Error No such file or directory Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
```

How to solve this issue ?!!

Comment: Open a terminal and enter `nautilus`. You will probably see some error messages in the terminal. Copy these and paste them into your question, so we can see what goes wrong.

Comment: the output is `Nautilus-Share-Message: 15:54:00.564: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
`

Comment: If you use Samba, you should have such a directory. Perhaps you can reinstall Samba: `sudo apt install --reinstall samba`. If you don't use Samba you might as well `sudo apt remove` it.

Comment: I don't have samba `Package 'samba' is not installed, so not removed` .. I don't need it.